# Проблема с subprocess в Python

Tags: python, subprocess

возникла следующая проблема. Запускаю свою программу, которая при нажатии кнопки запускает subprocess с чат-ботом и переводит его консоль в окно. Внутри пайчарм всё прекрасно работает, но вот если запускать скрипт просто как файл .py он не запускает subprocess или запускает неправильно, так и не понял. При попытке взаимодейстововать с чат-ботом, который якобы запущен там в subprocess выдает ошибку:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1 (start_skinless_mail):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Я\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\Users\Я\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Я\PycharmProjects\SkinlessMail\hran.py", line 50, in start_skinless_mail
output = proc.stdout.readline().decode("utf-8")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 14: invalid continuation byte
```

Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import sys
import subprocess
import threading
def main():
   root = Tk()
   root.geometry('500x240')
   root.resizable(width=False,height=False)
   frame = Frame(root,bg="#a30a0a")
   frame.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
   skinm = Button(frame,text="SkinlessMail",bg='#8a0000',font=10,pady=10,padx=5,fg='white',width=25,command=skinlessmail)
   skinm.pack(side=LEFT)
   root.mainloop()
def skinlessmail():
   no = '#a30a0a'
   root = Tk()
   root.geometry('800x600')
   root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
   root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
   root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
   frame = Frame(root, bg="#a30a0a")
   frame.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
   def start_skinless_mail():
       global proc
       proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", "SkinlessMail.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
       while True:
           output = proc.stdout.readline().decode("utf-8")
           if not output and proc.poll() is not None:
               break
           root.console_redirector.write(output)
   def run_script():
       skinless_mail_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_skinless_mail)
       skinless_mail_thread.start()

   def close_script():
       global proc
       proc.kill()
   frame.grid_columnconfigure(5, weight=1)
   frame.grid_rowconfigure(7, weight=1)
   skins = Button(frame, text="Старт", bg='#8a0000', font=10, pady=10, padx=5, fg='white', width=25,command=run_script)
   skins.grid(row=2, column=6, pady=4, padx=16)
   skins = Button(frame, text="Стоп", bg='#8a0000', font=10, pady=10, padx=5, fg='white', width=25,command=close_script)
   skins.grid(row=3, column=6, pady=4, padx=16)
   title = Label(frame, text='ИСТОРИЯ', bg=no, font=10, fg='white', width=25)
   title.grid(row=6, columnspan=7, pady=8)
   class ConsoleRedirector:
       def __init__(self, console_text_widget):
           self.console_text_widget = console_text_widget
       def write(self, message):
           self.console_text_widget.configure(state='normal')
           self.console_text_widget.insert(tk.END, message)
           self.console_text_widget.configure(state='disabled')
           self.console_text_widget.see(tk.END)
       def flush(self):
           pass
   root.console_text_widget = tk.Text(root, state='disabled')
   root.console_text_widget.grid(row=8, columnspan=7, pady=4)
   root.console_text_widget.config(height=15)
   root.console_redirector = ConsoleRedirector(root.console_text_widget)
   sys.stdout = root.console_redirector
   sys.stderr = root.console_redirector
   root.mainloop()
main()
```

Comment: Видимо когда вы "просто запускаете" ваш файл, либо не находится питон, либо вызываемый файл, ошибку `subprocess` пишет в кодировке `cp866`, соответственно, она не может расшифроваться как `utf-8`. Для начала попробуйте сделать `.decode("cp866")` и посмотрите, что будет в `output`, какая ошибка.

Comment: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f4c3' in position 57: character maps to <undefined>
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0] -  получил эту ошибку. Попробовал убрать из кода перевод вывода из сабпроцесса в консоль внутри tkinter и всё прекрасно работает. Ошибка видимо там